# How can I tell if Octave is busy?

Tags: octave

I was wondering how I can tell if the Octave is busy doing something, or free and ready to accept new commands. There is no message on statue bar, or any other type of indicator.

For now I'm using disp("Busy..."); at the beginning of m-file and disp("Done"); or beep() at the end of m-file to see when the calculation is finished.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Should not a new "octave:2>" line appear with incremented number ?

Comment: Oh my god! why I didn't thought of that! you are right. there is a >> appears when the process is done. Thank you my friend!

Comment: Where does it appear? I can't find it. Thanks in advance and sorry for this stupid question.